# Hadoop No space left on device erro when there is space available

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I have 5 Linux machines cluster. There are 3 data nodes and one master. At now about 50% hdfs storage is available on each data nodes. But I run a mapreduce job, It is failed with following error

```
2017-08-21 17:58:47,627 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for blk_6835454799524976171_3615612 bad datanode[0] 10.11.1.42:50010
2017-08-21 17:58:47,628 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block blk_6835454799524976171_3615612 in pipeline 10.11.1.42:50010, 10.11.1.43:50010: bad datanode 10.11.1.42:50010
2017-08-21 17:58:51,785 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error in syncLogs: java.io.IOException: No space left on device
```

While on each system `df -h` gives following information

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    5.9G   84K  5.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    5.9G  9.1M  5.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                    5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G  6.8G   44G  14% /
/dev/sdb                 1.8T  535G  1.2T  31% /mnt/11fd6fcc-1f87-4f1e-a53c-54cc7117759c
/dev/mapper/centos-home  412G  155G  59M  100% /home
/dev/sda1                494M  348M  147M  71% /boot
tmpfs                    1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    1.2G     0  1.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

As clear from above that my sdb dicsk (SDD) is only 31% used but centos-home is 100%. While hadoop is using local file system in mapreduce job when there is enough HDFS available? Where is the problem? I have search at google and found many such problem but no one covers my situation.

Comment: You could try and free up some space in your `/centos-home` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Some of the yarn-logs are stored on local filesystem. Try freeing space on `/home` and that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`syncLogs` does not use HDFS, it writes to `hadoop.log.dir` so 
if you're using MapReduce, look for the value of `hadoop.log.dir` in /etc/hadoop/conf/taskcontroller.cfg.

If you're using YARN, look for the value of `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` in the yarn-site.xml.

One of these should point you to where you're writing your logs.  Once you figure out which filesystem has the problem, you can free space from there.

Another thing to remember is you could get "No space left on device" if you've exhausted your inodes on your disk.  `df -i` would show this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check how many inodes are used. If I undertand it right, if it is still the full disk, but all inodes has gone, the error would be still the same, "no space left".